# Finding all local maximum points of a function?

Tags: linear-algebra, nonnegative-matrices, nonlinear-optimization

Let ${\boldsymbol \theta}=(\theta_1,\theta_2,\ldots,\theta_n) \in{\mathbb T}^n$ and $P:{\mathbb T}^n\rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ be a function defined on $n$-torus as
$$
P({\boldsymbol \theta}) = \sum_{i<j}(1+\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j))^2.
$$
What are **local** maximum points of $P$?

One can simply show that the global maximum is ${\boldsymbol \theta} = (\theta,\theta, \ldots,\theta)$ for all $\theta \in {\mathbb S}^1$, but the question is regarding the *local* maximum points of it.

Comment: certainly, $x=(a,\dots,a)$ is a global maximum for any $a$, not only for $a=0$.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik, Thanks! I have edited it.

Comment: This looks like a problem from undergraduate calculus, and hence not appropriate for MO.  If it is "research level", please add some motivation and discussion of why.  If it is not "research level", math.stackexchange would be a better fit for it.

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd This is a potential function originated from a research problem in theory of differential equation for a biological system!

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd Is it really that easy to *explicitly* locate all the local maxima? There are vaguely similar innocuous functions on higher tori where locating the minima could solve the notorious circulant Hadamard conjecture. I vote to re-open

Comment: @YemonChoi: That's quite possible — I didn't try to answer the question myself.  I keep firmly to a rule that I prefer questions that have motivation and background and so on, and I vote to "put on hold" questions that lack them.  If OP includes some background and discussion into the question — what he's tried, what kind of answer he's looking for — then I'll join you in voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{\partial P}{\partial x_k} = 2 \sum_i \sin(x_i-x_k)\left(1 + \cos(x_i-x_k)\right )
$$
We know, local maximums satisfy the equality : $\nabla P({\rm x}) = {\rm 0}$

Some obvious solutions are $x_i - x_j = k\pi, k \in \mathbb Z $

Comment: How can you solve this system of nonlinear equations? besides you need $D^2f({\rm x}) \ge 0$. I have tried these all!

Comment: @MohammadKhosravi Are numerical solutions suitable for you?

Comment: @MohammadKhosravi For the case when $n=3$ and if we set $x_1 = 1$ plotting the function using wolframalpha gives [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%28%281%2Bcos%28x-1%29%29%5E2+%2B+%281%2Bcos%28y-1%29%29%5E2%29). I think it could give some ideas to guess solutions.

Comment: I have guessed the solutions numerically! but I can't prove it! The solution is ${\rm x}_i -{\rm x}_j = 0, \mod \pi$.

Comment: @MohammadKhosravi Those solutions are obvious solutions of the gradient equation (since $\sin(x_i - x_j) = 0$). If you are sure that there aren't any other local maximum, so you've done! and what are you looking for?

Comment: That is the question that whether there is any other solution which yields in local maximum!

Comment: @MohammadKhosravi Have you tried finding minimum of $\sum_k (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}({\rm x}))^2$ ?

Comment: I will try this idea!

Comment: it is generally not possible to local all equilibria and local minimum of the energy function of Kuramoto model.. However, if the underlying adjacency graph is tree, ring graph, then it can be explicitly found. Complete graph as in your case, maybe not.